# Suppress OneNote adding itself to startup items

Tags: windows-7, boot, microsoft-onenote

I use the MS Office OneNote app from time to time, but not daily. However, every time I use it, it sticks itself back into the Windows startup items, and helps itself to a chunk of RAM and boot time. Just getting a little tired of pulling up msconfig every time I use the thing. Does anyone know how to keep it from continually sticking itself into startup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OneNote 2010, from the Options menu on the Backstage file tab choose the Display option in the left menu and uncheck 'Place OneNote icon in the notification area of the task bar'.

In OneNote 2007, it is in the "Other" option, not the Display option.

Comment: I guess sometimes I'm just not going to find the checkbox I'm looking for until someone spells it out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did all recommendations and it still opened. The duplication mentioned above made me think so I look at Norton manager for start ups and found one note in there checked on. So uncheck in there too and it looks like that did the trick.