# How to keep Microsoft OneNote from autostarting on boot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-onenote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppress OneNote adding itself to startup items](https://superuser.com/questions/243714/suppress-onenote-adding-itself-to-startup-items)

How do I keep Microsoft OneNote from autostarting when I boot my computer?

Windows 7.

Comment: Is it actually opening at log on, or are you just talking about the icon that shows up in the tray by the clock?

Comment: I have tried Autoruns, I can't find anything that starts One Note,
The actual program starts and opens.
I have downloaded and started using Process Explorer instead of Task Manager.
I have gone into MSConfig, and looked at Startup, still nothing that leads to One note.

Wayne

Comment: https://dev.to/techdev/how-to-stop-onenote-automatic-start-with-windows-48n7

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Start menu, click Run -> type `msconfig` and press Enter -> Go to the 'Startup' tab -> find and uncheck Microsoft OneNote from the list.

If you can't find it in there, it may be hidden...Run [**Autoruns for Windows**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and you should be able to find it in there...

Comment: Microsoft One Note is not in the Startup tab list

Comment: Have you tried Autoruns @Wayne?